# Programming languages implemented in assembly language

Tags: programming-languages, assembly, forth

Recently I've stumbled upon [JONESFORTH](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2452%29%20%28%5BGIT%20repo%5D%28http://git.annexia.org/?p=jonesforth.git;a=summary), which is an interpreter for the Forth programming language implemented in plain assembly language.

I find this implementation interesting, because it shows how a language can be implemented in assembly language, although I understand that implementing a language can be a serious portability tradeoff.

So I wondered if there are any other programming languages implemented in assembly language, whose source are still available (and maybe are even still under active development)?

Comment: I actually wanted to make it a community wiki, but don't know how, sorry

Comment: Would this workaround do it? ;) (1) Take an abritary language implementation in C or C++. (2) Compile. (3) Disassemble the executable. (I had a hard time not adding "... Profit!")

Comment: Forth is somewhat unique in how it is designed in an incremental fashion so that you write a very small set of commands in assembly and then write the rest in Forth itself. You then get portability by having a minimal set that needs to be ported. Some Lisps share this characteristic as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it is *possible* to write a language implementation in assembly, for most languages it is not really advisable to do so for a variety of reasons: assembly code is notoriously difficult to develop and maintain, and it is by definition not portable.

That said, some languages are significantly easier to produce implementations for:

- It is very easy to produce an [assembly implementation](http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/brainfuck-programming-language/brainfuck-programming-language.asp) for [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)
- [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) has a number of implementations in assembly, which is why it is used in the firmware of several non-PC workstations. You can find some assembly implementations for various platforms [here](http://www.forth.org/compilers.html).
- Many [BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) interpretters have been written in assembly - in fact that was probably true for most BASIC implementations in the various home computers of the late '70s and early '80s. Some can be found [here](http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/basic/).

Comment: Forth - all the power and flexibility of assembly language combined with the readability and maintainability of assembly language

Comment: Teasing forth for its readability is a little mean: that is really the fault of the programmer.

Answer (score 7):

Several versions of [Turbo Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal) since 1.0 [were written in assembly language](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2008/11/18/39175). It was the only way to fit an editor, compiler, a debugger, and the compiled program into the 64 KB RAM of the time, and it provided for blazing edit-compile-debug speeds never witnessed before.

Answer (score 7):

Pico Lisp recently (in the past few years) switched from C to x86-64 assembler.  That's the only example I can think of that was undertaken in the "modern" era.  There are some older Lisps bootstrapped from assembler still in use.  Actually wait, someone recently wrote a Scheme in ARM assembler (http://armpit.sourceforge.net/index.html).  I don't know why they would have done such a crazy-sounding thing and I haven't looked at it closely.  Of course it's very common to write in C and add some asm functions to implement call/cc or the like.

The BDS C compiler from the 1980's was written in 8080 assembler and the source code was released a few years ago, but it's mostly of historical interest.

Comment: PicoLisp also has a reference implementation written in Java. (Which is also used to compile picolisp when there is no picolisp on the system already.)

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately every language is implemented in assembler, a c-compiler must map + to an assembler instruction, somehow, somewhere. There is only a great variability in how large a part of a language is in the assembler kernel, and how large part of the language is defined in the language itself.
If you look at jonesforth you will see that a part of the kernel, even in the assembler file, is in fact Forth code, not assembler code.

So the criterion may be whether the language of the main program is assembler or the language itself. More important may be whether a languages needs another language to be build, e.g. a lisp implementation in Pascal, Gforth implemented using C. It may be a liability to be dependant from a compiler that you don't control, and language standards that may make some practices obsolescent. Keeping up with new features of a processor in a compiler, requires in depth assembly knowledge, whether your compiler is written in itself or in assembly.

As long as you have the source the language is not dead. So you can look at FIG-Forth's (1980). jonesforth has part of its inspiration from my ciforth, an i86 assembler Forth for 16/32/64 bits.

I can recomment especially `` yourforth '' a Forth in assembler that I made specifically for educational purposes. It has exercises, but those are not completed yet: https://bitbucket.org/avanderhorst/yourforth

Answer (score 2):

Although not purely in assembly, the vm and some other sections of luajit is written in macro'd assembly, for multiple platforms (mainly x86), purely for the speed it provides (mike paul may have other reasons, but I beleive this is the main one). The macro processor is also custom built as well, using lua however.